# Sqlite3 DB Path for download

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is anybody know from which link i am able to download SQlite3 Database for Xcode. I want to use Database in my project in Xcode4.2. Please provide link to download it.

Comment: I want to download software sqlite3 . Is there any link for downloading it?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?6sxbsfllviyc1o5

Answer (score 2):

Its not like download the database. There are some options where you have to create sqlite3 database in your project through terminal or Mozilla firefox (Provide Add-ons for sqlite3 manager - Google it). After creating DB you have to add libsqlite3.0.dylib Framework in your project provided by apple developer documentation.

For further information follow [This](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/) tutorial. Which would be great start to work on sqlite3.

Comment: I want to downlaod DB..I know code for How to use DB , but i don't have sqlite3. Kindly see that image : http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/SQLite_Database_Browser_icon.png

Comment: Try this link.
http://mac.softpedia.com/progDownload/SQLite-Database-Browser-Download-30549.html

Comment: Thanx for giving me link